# $X,Y\sim U(0,1)$ are independent, $W=\max (X,Y)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, uniform-distribution

$X,Y\sim U(0,1)$  are independent, $W=\max (X,Y)$.

1. How do I find the PDF of $W$?
2. How do I find the expectation of $W$ at two ways: 1. with the PDF of $W$ and **without** the PDF of $W$.

I ask this Q before few days, but now I want show you me solution and ask if it's right (and ask to tell me where I wrong):

We assume that $0<t<1$ becuase otherwise the function $(f)$ returns 0.
1. Lets say: $W=\max(X,Y)\Rightarrow W(t)=P(t>X)\cdot P(t>Y)=(1-P(t<X))(1-P(t<Y))$ because they are independent.
We know that $P(t<X)=F_X(t)=t$ (Because $X\sim U(0,1)$), and this is why: $F_W(t)=(1-t)^2$ (if $0<t<1$ otherwise is $0$).
So $f_W(t)=F'_W(t)=2t-2$.

2:
a. $$E(W(t))=\int _{0}^1 t\cdot f_W dt=\int_0^12t^2-2tdt=\left[\frac{2t^3}{3}-\frac{2t^2}2\right]^1 _0$$
I dot here something negative and I don't know why...
Please tell me where my mistake here....

b.
Here I'll show you the idea, and I'd like to know if I'm right...
[image]
$$\iint_{D_1}\max(X,Y)dxdy+\iint_{D_2}\max(X,Y)dxdy \\= \iint_{D_1}xdxdy+\iint_{D_2}ydxdy$$

I'm right? If I'm wrong please tell me where are my mistakes (at all the question).
Thank you!

Comment: $F_X(t):=P[X\le t]= t$ and consequently $F_W(t)=t^2$.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}U=\int_{0}^{\infty}1-F_{U}\left(u\right)du$ is true for
any nonnegative rv $U$. That can be used to find $\mathbb{E}W$ without
using the PDF of $W$. Your way will work too I think.

Comment: @drhab - so my mistake is that $F_W\ne (1-t),\;F_W=t$? So $E(W)=\frac13$, right?

Comment: @drhab, I didn't understand your second comment, about the Expectation... Can you explain it more please? that it will be more clear to me. thank you!!

Comment: As I said $F_{W}\left(t\right)=t^{2}$ (not $t$ or $1-t$). Then
$f_{W}\left(t\right)=2t$ (the derivative of $F_{W}$) and $\mathbb{E}W=\int_{0}^{1}tf_{W}\left(t\right)dt=2\int_{0}^{1}t^{2}dt=\frac{2}{3}$.
Another way to find $W$ is using the equality $\mathbb{E}W=\int_{0}^{1}1-F_{W}\left(t\right)dt=\int_{0}^{1}1-t^{2}dt=\frac{2}{3}$.
However, if you are not familiar with the general formula $\mathbb{E}U=\int_{0}^{\infty}1-F_{U}\left(u\right)du$
for nonnegative rv $U$, then don't pay attention to it and try to
find $\mathbb{E}W$ on your own alternative way.

Comment: @drhab, sorry! I meant: $F_X(t)=t$ and not $F_X(t)=1-t$.... Right? Thank you!

Comment: @drhab, it doesn't work...:-( at my way I get $\frac13$, why?? Thank you!

Comment: $\int\int_{D_{1}}xdxdy=\int\int_{D_{1}}xdydx=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{x}xdydx=\int_{0}^{1}x\int_{0}^{x}dydx=\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}dx=\frac{1}{3}$.
Also $\int\int_{D_{2}}ydxdy=\frac{1}{3}$ so $\mathbb{E}W=\frac{2}{3}$.